# flutter passing data into dropdown button

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app, and I want to be able to access a parent class's state from a DropdownButton.  The state variable I would like to access is called whichsc and it is indicated in the comments. Here is my code:

```
//I call Choices as follows.  I could be wrong about how to do this to pass in whichsc, but I believe I am correct

child: Choices(whichsc: 1),
```

```
//this is my choices widget
class Choices extends StatefulWidget {
final int whichsc;

Choices({this.whichsc});

@override 
_ChoicesState createState() => _ChoicesState()
}

class _ChoicesState extends State<Choices> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return DropdownButton<String>(
          items: [
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: "1",
              child: Image.asset('lib/images/img1.jpeg'),
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: "2",
              child: Image.asset('lib/images/img2.jpeg'),
          ),
          ],
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _value = value;

            });
            print("NewValue: ${_value}");

            Provider.of<SendDataModel>(context, listen: false).changeOption(this.whichsc, int.parse(value));  //this is where I want whichsc to be accessed.  It is just a state management provider call
          },
          hint: Text("Item"),
          value: _value,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to pass it into the "Choices" class. But in order to access it in the _ChoicesState class which extends the Choices class you can either do the same thing that you did in your code example and require it in the constructor or you can reference it by calling widget.whichsc. I don't believe this.whichsc will work because this in that case is the state class not the class you passed the value into.

If you are going to reference widget.whichsc then you need to make sure you do it somewhere within the build function because that is the only place that has the context of the Choices class.

Comment: Hi @JMo, thanks for helping out!  How would I reference it by calling widget.whichsc?  Also, since Dropdown widget is a built-in widget from flutter, how would I go about passing in a parameter?  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @JMo, I just called it in the code using widget.whichsc and it worked!  Thanks for that!  would you mind explaining briefly why this worked though?

Comment: this.whichsc only looks at the instance of the current class. In your case it was the state class that extended the Choices class. widget.whichsc on the other hand looks at the current context. And because your build method passes the context (which are the parameters of the class it extended) it is able to reference those params.